# Best control for Explorer-like image browser

Tags: c#, wpf, controls, thumbnails

I want to create a program with interface similar to Windows Explorer, in that is displays thumbnails and name, size etc., and was wandering what would be the control to use.

What I want it to do is this:

- Display all pictures is the folder(s) selected by the code. There can be hundreds of them, using hundreds of MB, so I need it to only render the visible part and not the whole thing
- Allow selecting one or more pictures for use with other parts of the code (apply a filter, copy to somewhere else etc.). Of course some of the selected images might not be visible, and so might not be rendered
- it should allow the use of several lines of info per item (name, size, date...)
- The thumbnails size should be easily changeable, and I need to reflow the items if more or less items fit in a column (it could be done with code, but I prefer it to be in the control). Of course this should not change the list of selected items (so selected items are not identified by row and column, but by index)

What I have by now is this (it will go to a separate function later)

```
thumb[] thumbs;

public MainWindow() {
    InitializeComponent();

    int i;
    string[] files=Directory.GetFileSystemEntries(@"C:\images","*.jpg",SearchOption.AllDirectories);
    System.Drawing.Size mySize=new System.Drawing.Size(128,128);

    thumbs=new thumb[files.Length];
    for(i=0; i<files.Length ;i++){
        thumbs[i]=new thumb(files[i],mySize);
    }
    //MessageBox.Show("Loaded "+i.ToString()+" images");
}
```

And this (later I might switch to use `Image.GetThumbnailImage()` as the base for resizing):

```
class thumb {
    public Bitmap bmp;
    public Size   originalSize;
    public string path;

    public thumb(string path, Size targetSize) {
        Bitmap tempBmp;
        this.path=path;
        tempBmp=new Bitmap(path);
        originalSize=tempBmp.Size;
        bmp=new Bitmap(tempBmp,targetSize);
        tempBmp.Dispose(); //get our memory back
    }
}
```

Comment: Your question is off topic for this website because: *Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.*

Comment: I'm not looking for a book or a tool, but for what control fits the job.
There is a closed list of controls available in WPF, and each have it's own uses.

I did state what I want, and what I have been doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ListBox as a container for controls that will hold thumbnail, name, etc. You can either create a DataTemplate for ListBoxItem or create new UserControl and use it as a Content for the ListBox.

Using WrapPanel will allow you to make it very responsive to the size of the application window.

Here is a sample that you need to change according to your needs, but it's a good starting point.

```
<ListBox x:Name="ListOfImages" ItemsSource="{Binding Images}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Width="120" Margin="10" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                <Image Source={Binding ImagePath}" />
                <TextBlock Text={Binding Name}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
        <WrapPanel />
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
</ListBox>
```